# Problema en emulador Google Maps

Tags: android, xamarin

Me Podrían ayudar con este error en el emulador de Android SDK Manager, tengo instalado todo en Android sdk Manager(Google Play Services)estoy usando el emulador marshmallow Android 6.0 API 23.

Mi aplicación muestra la geo-localización en google maps lo cual consume una API, el problema no es la API, es el emulador lo cual no muestra los puntos, la key que genero en google esta correcto, el emulador no me muestra los puntos de las ubicaciones.

[image: error]

cuando intento instalar Google Play Services desde el emulador me marca los siguientes errores 
[image: error2]

y cuando lo intento abrir desde la Play store me marca el siguiente error[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias @Daniel primeramente instala Google Play Services, el botón que genera la aplicación te puede llevar directo a la tienda.

Comment: @Jorgesys me marca el error de que no tengo ningun dispositivo, ya edite la pregunta y agrege algunas capturas o hay otro emulador para poder probar el proyecto.

Comment: lo de ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME es porque no reconoce el protocolo intent:// te recomiendo abrir la aplicación Playstore pero recuerda que debes tener una cuenta de google para instalar aplicaciones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En este caso el mensaje mostrado en tu aplicación se refiere a que **tu aplicación requiere para un buen funcionamiento de tener instalado en tu dispositivo [**Google Play Services](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms&hl=en)****

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este caso tu aplicación usa Google Maps por lo tanto requiere de Google Play Services, para solucionar esto debes instalar [**Google Play Services**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms&hl=en) en tu dispositivo físico o emulador.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: gracias lo que hice fue cambiar de emulador a uno mas reciente porque no queria instalar el google play services.

Comment: @Daniel revisa en ese emulador las aplicaciones instaladas, en realidad debes tener google play services para poder usar los mapas.